# Wordpress post insertion from PHP file

Tags: php, posts, mysql, xml

I have a website it's contains a lot of news, i have to list this news in one PHP file , now i want to insert each news in wordPress as a Post.. what is the best practice way to do that (the news are more than 100 articles) , how can i build manually the XML file so i can import it in WordPress ? or what is the post insert function , so i can call it in PHP file ..?

the news are here :
https://www.steuerlex24.de/steuerkanzlei-koerfer/information_steuer-news

there is an API to export the news in XML file.

Thanks a lot

Comment: One way would be to grab the XML file, turn it into an object using something like PHP's [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-string.php), and then iterate over the object to insert your posts in the way Pim describes in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The PHP way**

If you want to use PHP, you can use `wp_insert_post` to insert posts programatically. Basically you want to provide an array of post information (title, content, date...). You can read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

But the problem is you should not run that function to import all 100 posts. I used to solve the same problem: Migrate 34k posts from old site to new site using WordPress. Here is what I did:

- Write a PHP script to crawl the post URLs of target site. I wrap it in a Page template. I use `Simple HTML DOM` to extract data from page. I append the result to the page itself.
- Still on that page, after getting all URLs I need, I use Ajax to insert post one by one. Use Simple HTML DOM to extract data, then use `wp_insert_post` to insert post to database with the crawled data

  - Get URL from the list append in the previous step
  - Use Simple HTML DOM to extract data from that URL
  - Use `wp_insert_post` to create post with extracted data.
  - Repeat that action until all done.

**The CSV way**

IMO, build a WordPress xml file to import is hard. You can think about a simpler alternative choice is CSV. Build a CSV file is more straight forward and simpler. Then you can use a CSV import plugin to create posts on your new site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).

```
$args = array (
   'post_title' => $your_title,
   'post_content' => $your_content,
   'post_status' => 'publish'
)

$post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
```